# How to make SVN STATUS not show modifications to directory's properties?

Tags: svn, status

```
$ svn status
 M      .
 M      Directory1                 // dir property modification
 M      Directory2                 // dir property modification
M       Directory1/index.php
M       Directory2/index.php
```

How can I prevent those modifications to directory's properties from showing?

Comment: Quick and dirty - filter out all output lines that starts with ' M': `svn stat | grep -v '^ M'`. Although there are 7 possible columns in `svn stat` output, so it will filter out lines that starts with ' M' but also has other modification flags.

Comment: It's good enough for my needs, thanks!